# How to set context parameter ResolveToEmailName

Tags: email

I have the following code in my workflow, but I dont know what to put in one of the parameters. It mentions context but what is context on the microsoft site? I don't know what it's referring to.

```
ResolveToEmailName(**what should I put here ?** , GroupName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a DependencyProperty of type WorkflowContext as shown below. Then use __Context as first parameter in above method. Check [this](http://the-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/01/sending-emails-to-sharepoint-group.html) for an example.

```
public static DependencyProperty __ContextProperty = System.Workflow.ComponentModel.DependencyProperty.Register("__Context",
            typeof(WorkflowContext), typeof(ExpandSharePointGroup));

        [Description("Context")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public WorkflowContext __Context
        {
            get
            {
                return ((WorkflowContext)(base.GetValue(__ContextProperty)));
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(__ContextProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi The ExpandSharePointGroup gives an error, could not be found, missing a Using directive or assembly reference ?

Comment: Is this a compile error, yes than include assemblies and namespaces as shown in link above.